# How do i check if 2 sentences are similar in my chatbot

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I made the simplest kind of chatbot possible. Its one that answers your questions depending on what you wanted it to answer to the same question before. The code is kinda like this:

```
question = []
answer = []
qcount = 0
stop = 0

b = 0

while stop == 0:
    b = 0
    q = input("Ask me anything: ")
    if q == "stop":
        exit()
    for i in range(qcount):
        if q == question[i]:
            b = 1
            print(answer[i])


    if b == 0:
        question.append(q)
        qcount = qcount + 1

        a = input("How should i answer that? ")
        answer.append(a)
```

Is there a way of turning

```
if q == question[i]
```

to

```
if q is similar to question[i]
```

?

Comment: Btw q and all elements in question[] are strings or sentences. If you could give me some code i could copy and paste, that would be great!

Comment: What have you tried to find "similar" questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To Make A Fuzzy Finder Do This By Replacing `if q == question[i]` to `if q in question[i]` this does not look for a specific word but looks for a keyword**

```
question = []
answer = []
qcount = 0
stop = 0

b = 0

while stop == 0:
    b = 0
    q = input("Ask me anything: ")
    if q == "stop":
        exit()
    for i in range(qcount):
         if q in question[i]:  # HERE IS THE ANSWER
            b = 1
            print(answer[i])


    if b == 0:
        question.append(q)
        qcount = qcount + 1

        a = input("How should i answer that? ")
        answer.append(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Aryan Mishra already provided you the answer. I have similar answer for you. You can try this as well. You dont need counters and exit statements. You can define the while statement itself as a gate keeper.

I made some more improvements. While this will NOT give you a perfect chatbot, it comes closer.

```
question = []
answer = []

q = input("Ask me anything: ")
while q.lower() != 'stop':
    i = -1
    z = q.lower().split()
    z.sort()

    for x in question:
        y = x.split()
        y.sort()
        if all(elem in y for elem in z):
            i = question.index(x)
    if i >= 0:
        print(answer[i])
    else:
        question.append(q.lower())
        a = input("How should i answer that? ")
        answer.append(a)
    q = input("Ask me anything: ")
```

Output:

```
Ask me anything: What is your Name
How should i answer that? Joe
Ask me anything: What your name
Joe
Ask me anything: name
Joe
Ask me anything: your name
Joe
Ask me anything: what name
Joe
Ask me anything: what is name
Joe
```

As you can see, when you ask "what is name" it still assumes you are asking what is your name. You need to work with this to get to a more sophisticated bot. Hope this helps you move in the right direction.

My previous answer is also posted here. Since we are comparing a string to a list, it has to an exact match. checking for q in question does not really give you an advantage. You will need to split the words and compare them. Thats what I did in my new response (see above)

```
question = []
answer = []

q = input("Ask me anything: ")
while q.lower() != 'stop':
    if q.lower() in question:
        i = question.index(q.lower())
        print (answer[i])
    else:
        question.append(q.lower())
        a = input("How should i answer that? ")
        answer.append(a)
    q = input("Ask me anything: ")
```